# How to change table row on every fifth cell using while or for?

Tags: php

Let's say we have a query that gives a result from database's records. I want to put those records on a table, but not like row after row. I would like to make a table that will change row on every fifth cell. How can I do this using `while` or `for`?

Here is just an example of what I have made for now, but I can't make it change row on every fifth cell...

```
<table>
<tr>
<?php $count = 0; while ($count <= 5){ ?>
<td><?php echo $id[$count]->id; $usrname[$count]->usrname;</td>
<?php $count++;}?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Any idea???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Modulo_operation_expression):

```
if($count % 5 == 4) {
  // end the current row, and start a new one
  echo "</tr><tr>";
```

It divides `$count` by 5 and takes the remainder. So once in every 5 steps, it is 4 (at `$count` is 4, 9, 14, etc) and you can generate something different for every fifth record.

---

If you apply this on your code example, you get this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<?php
$count = 0;
while ($count <= 5) {
  if($count % 5 == 4) {
    // Generate a new row
    echo "<\tr><tr>";
  }
  ?><td><?php echo $id[$count]->id." ".$usrname[$count]->usrname;?></td><?php
  $count++;
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying here, but this moment, my head is ready to explode... So, how would you apply this on my example? Thank you for your time!!!

Comment: @Veger I think he wants to show 5 entries in one row, then switching to new table row, showing another 5 entries. Your solution is good for changing the row colors, but not here I guess ...

Comment: @Mahdi I reread the question carefully, and I think you are right! So I updated my answer again, thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1):

use array_chunk() before while or for
or set into loop:

```
if($count % 5 == 0) {
   echo "</tr><tr>";
   $count = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could works. You can combine it with an inner `for` loop as well. But the working code highly depends to the `Array` that you're looping inside. So you might need to customise the following code to fit your set up.

Note that I eliminate the `While` loop, 'cause you didn't provide the actual array. you can place it before `<tr>` basically.

```
<table>

    // you may start your while loop here
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $id[$count]->id; $usrname[$count]->usrname; $count++; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $id[$count]->id; $usrname[$count]->usrname; $count++; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $id[$count]->id; $usrname[$count]->usrname; $count++; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $id[$count]->id; $usrname[$count]->usrname; $count++; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $id[$count]->id; $usrname[$count]->usrname; $count++; ?></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: @DNA180 I exactly had the same issue while ago, when I wanted to make a classified ads website, where I had to show 5 columns, and then going to the next row. I guess you want exactly the same!

Comment: Yes my friend but I also want TDs to be in while statement. I think Veger has make a nice example, take a look!